# Retopologize with target topology

Tags: graphics, 3d, cgal

I am playing with CGAL and I came across a funny idea: copy and pasting topology. I know that, generally, this is called *to retopologize* a mesh, and Blender has something... but not exactly this, as far as I know.

The complete problem is:

Given two meshes `source` and `target`, create a mesh `output` that has the shape of `target` and the topology of `source`.

I am assuming here that these meshes are topologically the same, in the sense that they represent the same object (both spheres, or both tori, and so on).

As far as CGAL is concerned, I am not tied to this library.

Any hints would be welcome